# Elsarticle double-blind mode?

Tags: collaboration, elsarticle

Is there a double-blind review mode for `elsarticle.cls`?

The last journal I submitted to included a review mode for double-blind reviews that automatically removed most identifying info, e.g. authour names and contact info, but I don't see something like this for elsarticle. When I put it in `review` mode, i.e. with `\documentclass[review,5p,times]{elsarticle}` my name is still shown.

Also, is there a recommended way to handle self-references for double-blind drafts? I reference my previous paper, and my project web page. For now I just use a couple of macros to reference these, and when compiling for review, I redefine the macros to just have a short blurb in red to state that the content, e.g. citation/ URL has been removed for the review draft. Is there a better way to do this?

To clarify this second question, I have the following just before my front matter:

```
% DOUBLE-BLIND REVIEW STUFF
% ** Final version **
%\newcommand{\projectPage}{\url{http://www.mypage.com/project}}
%\newcommand{\citeMyPaper}{\cite{me2012}}

% ** Review version (double blind) **
\newcommand{\projectPage}{\textcolor{red}{(URL removed for review draft)}}
\newcommand{\citeMyPaper}{\textcolor{red}{(Citation removed for review draft)} }
```

When switching between final and review versions, I manually change which macros are commented out. If elsarticle has a blind review mode, there must be a way to do this switch automatically when using that mode?

Comment: not an answer, but this question may contain some helpful information: [efficient-ways-to-anonymize-a-document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41995/)

Comment: The most probable reason why Elsevier doesn't have this feature is their journals don't use double blind system (none of which I've submitted). Otherwise, it would have been forced into this class which is pretty recently redesigned completely.

Comment: It is a shame that this thread is closed, because I had exactly the same doubt!! Did anyone find a solution for this?

Comment: @Vincent: This was a while ago so I don't remember all the details, but I'm pretty sure I just set up a series of commands for inserting into the text anything which should be removed during peer review. Then, you can have two definitions of the commands: one for review and one for final drafts. Keep all the review versions in one big block and final ones in another and you can block comment/uncomment as needed. I have a partial example in my original question. I did not find a way to do this through ELSarticle at the time. Thanks.