# Is it possible to remove length, counter, dim, etc that have been declared?

Tags: macros, counters, lengths, dimensions

Let's see the following screenshot taken from [an answer of Efficient ways to anonymize a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45303/9467) and the given comment.

[image]

Is it possible to remove length, counter, dim, etc, that have been declared in a macro, before leaving the macro?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7994/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-declare-variables-locally-inside-macros-or-environments

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's not possible: `\newlength` allocates a register and this allocation is permanent. If you do the `\newlength` inside a group, you'll lose the register name at group end, but the register will not be reusable.

Actually it *might* be possible: define a macro `\startlocalallocations` that modifies `\newlength` and `\newcounter` in such a way that allocations from that point on are stored in a convenient macro, say `\allocationsmade`, and then define `\removelocalallocations` that uses `\allocationsmade` to restore the status as it was before the starting command.

While feasible (at least in principle), this is completely useless. Registers should be allocated *outside* macro definitions: they can be set and used as many times as one wants. So the correct way to define `\blind` is

```
\newlength{\sowide}
\newlength{\sohigh}
\def\blind#1{%
  ...
  \settowidth{\sowide}{#1}%
  \settoheight{\sohigh}{H}%
  ...}
```

and all will work. There's no need to allocate a temporary variable.

Note: the package `etex` allows for local allocations. But this is useful in contexts very different from this one: one can think to the allocation of a block of registers for some particular use, when they are not called by name, but by numbers. See the implementation of the float mechanism for a slightly different example in which a block of registers is allocated and they are called `\bx@A`, `\bx@B`, ..., `\bx@R` in order that the next free register can be used by knowing the number of the last one used.